# Validating Child record in multi-level wpf view

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datacontext

Lets say I have a set of model classes like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Job> Jobs { get; private set; }
}
public class Job
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? End { get; set; }
}
```

I set up my xaml like this to display a list of people and all details on a single view:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="200" DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
    <DockPanel Width="200" Margin="10,0">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Jobs}" Name="_jobList" DisplayMemberPath="Title" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <StackPanel Width="200" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_jobList, Path=SelectedItem}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Start}"/>
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding End}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

The DataContext for the entire Window is an ObservbleCollection of People. This seems to work fairly well. I would now like to add some validation and I have no idea where to start.

I would like to validate the Job fields so that the user cannot select another Job (or person) if the title is empty or a duplicate within the same person, or if the dates are out of order. Additionally, the Person cannot be changed if the name is empty.

I have read a bit about validation in WPF, but have not found any clear solution for this scenario. What is the best practice for doing something like this?

Also, is my binding ok the way I set the DataContext on the last panel like that? It works, but it feels a little sketchy. The alternative is declaring resources for the CollectionDataSources and I couldn't really figure that method out very easily either.

Comment: I've tried implementing IDataErrorInfo in my data classes and putting ValidatesOnDataErrors=True in my bindings. This correctly highlights erroneous fields, but does not prevent navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the validation part you can start here: http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/

After you understand the article you could modify your classes like this:
For example let's add a non-empty title validation for job title and job start date:

Job class:

```
 public class Job : IDataErrorInfo
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime? End { get; set; }

        public string Error
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
        {
            string result = null;
            if (columnName == "Title")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title))
                    result = "Please enter a Title ";
            }
            if (columnName == "Start")
            {
                if (Start == null)
                    result = "Please enter a Start Date";
                else if (Start > End)
                {
                    result = "Start Date must be less than end date";
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        }
    }
```

//////////Supposing we used a window called MainWindow for you xaml code it would look like
MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        x:Name="mainWindow">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="errorTemplate">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
                <Border Background="Red" DockPanel.Dock="right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="20" Height="20" CornerRadius="10"
                                    ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                    <TextBlock Text="!" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="white">
                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                    <Border BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="1" />
                </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="200" DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=FormHasNoNoErrors}"/>
            <DockPanel Width="200" Margin="10,0">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Jobs}" Name="_jobList" DisplayMemberPath="Title" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=FormHasNoNoErrors}" />
            </DockPanel>
            <StackPanel Width="200" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_jobList, Path=SelectedItem}">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Title, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" Validation.Error="Validation_OnError" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource errorTemplate}"/>
                <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Start, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" Validation.Error="Validation_OnError" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource errorTemplate}"/>
                <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding End}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

////////MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        public MainWindow()
        {
            var jobs1 = new ObservableCollection<Job>()
                            {
                                new Job() {Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), Title = "Physical Enginer"},
                                new Job() {Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), Title = "Mechanic"}

                            };
            var jobs2 = new ObservableCollection<Job>()
                            {
                                new Job() {Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), Title = "Doctor"},
                                new Job() {Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), Title = "Programmer"}

                            };
            var personList = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
                                   {
                                       new Person() {Name = "john", Jobs = jobs1},
                                       new Person() {Name="alan", Jobs=jobs2}
                                   };

            this.DataContext = personList;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Validation_OnError(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added)
                NoOfErrorsOnScreen++;
            else
                NoOfErrorsOnScreen--;
        }

        public bool FormHasNoNoErrors
        {
            get { return _formHasNoErrors; }
            set 
            { 
                if (_formHasNoErrors != value)
                {
                    _formHasNoErrors = value;
                     PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FormHasNoErrors")); 
                }
            }
        }

        public int NoOfErrorsOnScreen
        {
            get { return _noOfErrorsOnScreen; }
            set 
            { 
                _noOfErrorsOnScreen = value;
                FormHasNoNoErrors = _noOfErrorsOnScreen == 0 ? true : false;
            }
        }

        private int _noOfErrorsOnScreen = 0;
        private bool _formHasNoErrors = true;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate {};
    }
```

//////////////////////

> I would like to validate the Job
>   fields so that the user cannot select
>   another Job (or person) if the title
>   is empty or a duplicate within the
>   same person, or if the dates are out
>   of order. Additionally, the Person
>   cannot be changed if the name is
>   empty.

One simple solution is to disable the listboxes if the forms has errors (that's what I did in the code above), and enable them when there are no errors. Also you should probably put a nice red border with tooltip on them, explaining the user why he can't select anymore.

For validating if the title is duplicate within the same person, you could extend the validation mechanism above to have a ValidationService class that receives a Person and looks if the person who has the job also has another one with the same name.

public class Person: IDataErrorInfo
    {

```
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
    {
        //look inside person to see if it has two jobs with the same title
        string result = ValidationService.GetPersonErrors(this);
        return result;
     }
...
 }
```

> Also, is my binding ok the way I set
>   the DataContext on the last panel like
>   that? It works, but it feels a little
>   sketchy. The alternative is declaring
>   resources for the
>   CollectionDataSources and I couldn't
>   really figure that method out very
>   easily either.

It's not in the MVVM spirit, and if what you're doing is going to be something more than a small test project you should try learn MVVM (You could start here: http://fernandomachadopirizen.wordpress.com/2010/06/10/a-simple-introduction-to-the-model-view-viewmodel-pattern-for-building-silverlight-and-windows-presentation-foundation-applications/)

Then you would not bind to a list of persons directly but instead you would have some MainWindowViewModel class to which you bind. This MainWindowViewModel class would contain the list of persons and you would bind to that.
And for the selection you would have a CurrentJob  property in your MainWindowViewModel, that is the currently selected job, and you would bind to that:

Basically something like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPerson, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="200" DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=FormHasNoNoErrors}"/>
    <DockPanel Width="200" Margin="10,0">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Jobs}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentJob, Mode=TwoWay}", DisplayMemberPath="Title" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
    </DockPanel>
    <StackPanel Width="200">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentJob.Title}"/>
       .....
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

And your MainWindowViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : 
{
...
   //Public Properties
   public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonList ....
   public Job CurrentJob ....
....
}
```

Comment: I think the key is at the end there where you point out that I am not doing mvvm right, and it would be simpler to manage it all in a view model class. I definitely feel like I am fighting it the hard way.